# Getting an HTML video's controls to show only when it is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

How would I attach an event listening to a `video` element so that it has the attribute `controls` only after it has started playing (and subsequent pauses)?

What I have is

```
$('#new-normal-video').on('play',function(){
    $(this).prop("controls",true);
});
```

and for some reason that event isn't atttaching.

Comment: is the play event firing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it out here. It seems to be working for me. Make sure your video elements are added properly. If you are dynamically creating the video, the script might be calling before the video elements  are created. Here is a working JSfiddle for your problem

https://jsfiddle.net/rea00rz6/1/

```
$('#myVideo').click(function() {
  $('#myVideo').get(0).play();
});
$("#myVideo").on('play', function() {
  //my code here
  $('#myVideo').prop("controls", true);
});
```